# How to add tracing to a Rust microservice?

Tags: rust, microservices, jaeger, distributed-tracing

I built a microservice in Rust. I receive messages, request a document based on the message, and call a REST api with the results. I built the REST api with **warp** and send out the result with **reqwest**. We use jaeger for tracing and the "b3" format. I have no experience with tracing and am a Rust beginner.

**Question**: What do I need to add the the **warp** / **reqwest** source below to propagate the tracing information and add my own span?

My version endpoint (for simplicity) looks like:

```
pub async fn version() -> Result<impl warp::Reply, Infallible> {
    Ok(warp::reply::with_status(VERSION, http::StatusCode::OK))
}
```

I assume I have to extract e.g. the traceid / trace information here.

A reqwest call I do looks like this:

```
pub async fn get_document_content_as_text(
    account_id: &str,
    hash: &str,
) -> Result<String, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {

    let client = reqwest::Client::builder().build()?;
    let res = client
        .get(url)
        .bearer_auth(TOKEN)
        .send()
        .await?;
    if res.status().is_success() {}
    let text = res.text().await?;
    Ok(text)
}
```

I assume I have to add the traceid / trace information here.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that you're using [tracing](https://crates.io/crates/tracing) within your application and using [opentelemetry](https://crates.io/crates/opentelemetry) and [opentelemetry-jaeger](https://crates.io/crates/opentelemetry-jaeger) to wire it up to an external service. The specific provider you're using doesn't matter. Here's a super simple setup to get that all working that I'll assume you're using on both applications:

```toml
# Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
opentelemetry = "0.17.0"
opentelemetry-jaeger = "0.16.0"
tracing = "0.1.33"
tracing-subscriber = { version = "0.3.11", features = ["env-filter"] }
tracing-opentelemetry = "0.17.2"

reqwest = "0.11.11"
tokio = { version = "1.21.1", features = ["macros", "rt", "rt-multi-thread"] }
warp = "0.3.2"
```

```
opentelemetry::global::set_text_map_propagator(opentelemetry_jaeger::Propagator::new());
tracing_subscriber::registry()
    .with(tracing_opentelemetry::layer().with_tracer(
        opentelemetry_jaeger::new_pipeline()
            .with_service_name("client") // or "server"
            .install_simple()
            .unwrap())
   ).init();
```

---

Let's say the "client" application is set up like so:

```
#[tracing::instrument]
async fn call_hello() {
    let client = reqwest::Client::default();
    let _resp = client
        .get("http://127.0.0.1:3030/hello")
        .send()
        .await
        .unwrap()
        .text()
        .await
        .unwrap();
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // ... initialization above ...

    call_hello().await;
}
```

The traces produced by the client are a bit chatty because of other crates but fairly simple, and does not include the server-side:

[image: Jaeger trace from the client call]

---

Let's say the "server" application is set up like so:

```
#[tracing::instrument]
fn hello_handler() -> &'static str {
    tracing::info!("got hello message");
    "hello world"
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // ... initialization above ...

    let routes = warp::path("hello")
        .map(hello_handler);

    warp::serve(routes).run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3030)).await;
}
```

Likewise, the traces produced by the server are pretty bare-bones:

[image: Jaeger trace from the server handler]

---

The key part to marrying these two traces is to declare the client-side trace as the parent of the server-side trace. This can be done over HTTP requests with the `traceparent` and `tracestate` headers as designed by the [W3C Trace Context Standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/trace-context/). There is a [`TraceContextPropagator`](https://docs.rs/opentelemetry/latest/opentelemetry/sdk/propagation/struct.TraceContextPropagator.html) available from the opentelemetry crate that can be used to "extract" and "inject" these values (though as you'll see, its not very easy to work with since it only works on `HashMap<String, String>`s).

For the "client" to send these headers, you'll need to:

- get the current tracing `Span`
- get the opentelemetry `Context` from the `Span` (if you're not using tracing at all, you can skip the first step and use `Context::current()` directly)
- create the propagator and fields to propagate into and "inject" then from the `Context`
- use those fields as headers for reqwest

```
#[tracing::instrument]
async fn call_hello() {
    let span = tracing::Span::current();
    let context = span.context();
    let propagator = TraceContextPropagator::new();
    let mut fields = HashMap::new();
    propagator.inject_context(&context, &mut fields);
    let headers = fields
        .into_iter()
        .map(|(k, v)| {(
            HeaderName::try_from(k).unwrap(),
            HeaderValue::try_from(v).unwrap(),
        )})
        .collect();

    let client = reqwest::Client::default();
    let _resp = client
        .get("http://127.0.0.1:3030/hello")
        .headers(headers)
        .send()
        .await
        .unwrap()
        .text()
        .await
        .unwrap();
}
```

For the "server" to make use of those headers, you'll need to:

- pull them out from the request and store them in a `HashMap`
- use the propagator to "extract" the values into a `Context`
- set that `Context` as the parent of the current tracing `Span` (if you didn't use tracing, you could `.attach()` it instead)

```
#[tracing::instrument]
fn hello_handler(traceparent: Option<String>, tracestate: Option<String>) -> &'static str {
    let fields: HashMap<_, _> = [
        dbg!(traceparent).map(|value| ("traceparent".to_owned(), value)),
        dbg!(tracestate).map(|value| ("tracestate".to_owned(), value)),
    ]
    .into_iter()
    .flatten()
    .collect();

    let propagator = TraceContextPropagator::new();
    let context = propagator.extract(&fields);
    let span = tracing::Span::current();
    span.set_parent(context);

    tracing::info!("got hello message");
    "hello world"
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // ... initialization above ...

    let routes = warp::path("hello")
        .and(warp::header::optional("traceparent"))
        .and(warp::header::optional("tracestate"))
        .map(hello_handler);

    warp::serve(routes).run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3030)).await;
}
```

With all that, hopefully your traces have now been associated with one another!

[image: Jaeger trace from both the client and server]

Full code is available [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=41a62893f486a675a65751cb57d409f5) and [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3dba91c19591beaa1f4db58427f141b7).

---

<sup>Please, someone let me know if there is a better way! It seems ridiculous to me that there isn't better integration available. Sure some of this could maybe be a bit simpler and/or wrapped up in some nice middleware for your favorite client and server of choice... But I haven't found a crate or snippet of that anywhere!</sup>

Comment: Hi, great answer! What is the purpose of `opentelemetry::global::set_text_map_propagator`? I seem to be able to get the same correlation between traces without having to call this before initializing the tracing subscriber.

Comment: @gliderkite Huh, I'm not well-versed with the opentelemetry internals so maybe the interfacing between tracing and opentelemetry means it doesn't use the global text map propagator? I put it in the answer since its part of the [setup documentation](https://docs.rs/opentelemetry-jaeger/0.18.0/opentelemetry_jaeger/#quickstart) but that's good to know that it might not actually be needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a tracing filter into your warp filter pipeline.

From the [documentation](https://docs.rs/warp/0.3.1/warp/filters/trace/index.html) example:

```rust
use warp::Filter;

let route = warp::any()
    .map(warp::reply)
    .with(warp::trace(|info| {
        // Create a span using tracing macros
        tracing::info_span!(
            "request",
            method = %info.method(),
            path = %info.path(),
        )
    }));
```